# Strange behaviour of handlers in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a rails application with a resoruce items. I have noticed that if I add some handlers, they are removed when the page changes.

```
    <%=link_to "Add fund","#",:class=>"addfund btn btn-primary"%>
    <form class="addfundform hide"action="<%=addFund_item_path :id=>item.id %>">
      <input type="text" name="fund">
      <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn">
      <a href="#" class="cancelfund btn btn-warning" >Cancel</a>
    </form>
```

addfundform is hidden by default and when you click on addfund, the addfundform form is displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


function showfundform(){
    console.log("Hello")
    var $item=$(this);
    $item.next("form").show();
    return false;
}

$(".addfund").click(showfundform)


})
```

So when I click on addfund button, the form is displayed. It however disappears when i click the cancel button. (this is funny because i haven't added anything to it yet) After this, the addfund button doesn't do anything. As if the handlers had been removed. 
Also if I don't go to the items page. I go the new Item page, and then to the item page, the handler isn't loaded etiher

This rather wierd since I am not fetching anything via ajax. This is a rails4 app. I saw an error saying something about turbolinks, although I don't know any more

Comment: Did you add listener to some other page maybe with class selector and that code gets loaded e.g. $('.cancelfund').click(function() { $(self).hide(); } :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 comes with a feature of Turbolinks and it seems to be causing trouble. Follow these steps:-

Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.

and you should be good to go.